# Set the result of a query to a variable in MySQL (node js)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

How i can set result of a COUNT query to variable: 
I have a function:

```
exports.someFunction = function (req, res) {
    var user =  req.session.user,
    userId = req.session.session_id;
    if(userId == null){
       res.redirect("/login");
       return;
    }
    let sql = `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id_one = ? AND status = ?`;
    let post = [userId, 2];
    connection.query(sql, post, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.json(result);
        let a = setValue(result);
        console.log(a);
    });

};

function setValue (result) {
    let a = result;
}
```

When I set result of query to variable `a` I get undefined. Please help me fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alias for an easy access to the column name

```
  let sql = `SELECT COUNT(*) mycount FROM table WHERE id_one = ? AND status = ?`;

  .....
```

and access to the first element as

```
 console.log(result[0].mycount);
```